# c++ - Win32 window freezes after the first draw (directx 11)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, directx, directdraw

I have a standard win32 window, that I draw on with `D2D1`. Everything is responsive and runs smoothly. My problem is as follows: After the window is created, it calls `WM_PAINT` **once** and then gets "stuck" waiting for any user input (*ex. mouse move or click in the window area*). As it receives the input, it runs without any further problems. While this doesn't necessarily render the program nonfunctional, it seems highly unprofessional and... *ugly*. Oh, and what I mean by "stuck" is that the background processes still run without problems, so the loop runs as intended - however, the `WM_PAINT` isn't called for some reason.

Here is the current code:

### header file:

```
#define PROGRAM_FPS 30
#define GWINDOW_STYLE (WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_CLIPCHILDREN | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS)

class Application
{
public:
    Application();
    ~Application();

    // Register the window class and call methods for instantiating drawing resources
    HRESULT Initialize();

    // Process and dispatch messages
    void RunMessageLoop();

    static inline void SafeRelease(IUnknown * _X)
    {
        if(_X != NULL)
            _X->Release();
    };

    HRESULT SetFullscreen(bool);

private:

    // Time (ms) between frames of the application
    // Initiation: m_AppFPS_Div( (DWORD)1000.0 / (DWORD)PROGRAM_FPS )
    const DWORD m_AppFPS_Div;

    // Initialize device-independent resources.
    HRESULT CreateDeviceIndependentResources();

    // Initialize device-dependent resources.
    HRESULT CreateDeviceResources();

    // Release device-dependent resource.
    void DiscardDeviceResources();

    // Draw content.
    HRESULT OnRender();

    HRESULT LoadBitmapFromFile(
        ID2D1RenderTarget*,
        PCWSTR,
        UINT,
        UINT,
        ID2D1Bitmap **
        );

    // The windows procedure.
    static LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(
        HWND hWnd,
        UINT message,
        WPARAM wParam,
        LPARAM lParam
        );
    HWND m_hwnd;
    ID2D1Factory * m_pDirect2dFactory;
    ID2D1HwndRenderTarget * m_pRenderTarget;
    IWICImagingFactory *m_pIWICFactory;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush * m_pWhiteBrush;
    ID2D1SolidColorBrush * m_pGrayBrush;
    ID2D1LinearGradientBrush * m_pLinearGradientBrush;
    ID2D1Bitmap *m_LoadingPicture;
};
```

### parts of the .cpp file

```
void Application::RunMessageLoop()
{
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_WIN32APP));
    DWORD screen_last_refresh = 0;
    MSG msg;
    for(bool applicationRunning = true; applicationRunning;)
    {
        while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            if(msg.message == WM_QUIT)
            {
                applicationRunning = false;
            }

            if(!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
            {
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }

        /*** HERE I RUN VARIOUS BACKGROUND PROCESSES ***/

        while((GetTickCount() - screen_last_refresh) < m_AppFPS_Div)
            Sleep(2);
        InvalidateRect(msg.hwnd, NULL, false);
        screen_last_refresh = GetTickCount();
    }
}

LRESULT CALLBACK Application::WndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    LRESULT result = 0;
    if (message == WM_CREATE)
    {
        LPCREATESTRUCT pcs = (LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam;
        Application *pApp = (Application *)pcs->lpCreateParams;

        ::SetWindowLongPtrW(hwnd, GWLP_USERDATA, PtrToUlong(pApp) );
        InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, false);
        result = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        Application *pApp = reinterpret_cast<Application *>(static_cast<LONG_PTR>(
            ::GetWindowLongPtrW(
                hwnd,
                GWLP_USERDATA
                )));

        bool wasHandled = false;

        if (pApp)
        {
            switch (message)
            {
            case WM_SIZE:
                {
                    UINT width = LOWORD(lParam);
                    UINT height = HIWORD(lParam);
                    pApp->OnResize(width, height);
                }
                result = 0;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;

            case WM_DISPLAYCHANGE:
                {
                    InvalidateRect(hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
                }
                result = 0;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;

            case WM_PAINT:
                {
                    pApp->OnRender();
                    ValidateRect(hwnd, NULL);
                }
                result = 0;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;

            case WM_DESTROY:
                {
                    PostQuitMessage(0);
                }
                result = 1;
                wasHandled = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!wasHandled)
        {
            result = DefWindowProc(hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
        }
    }
    return result;
}

HRESULT Application::OnRender()
{
    HRESULT hr = S_OK;
    hr = CreateDeviceResources();
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
        m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Identity());

        /** HERE I HANDLE THE OPENING ANIMATION **/

        hr = m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    }

    if (hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
    {
        hr = S_OK;
        DiscardDeviceResources();
    }
    return hr;
}
```

So, I've tested it on 2 computers (both using Win 8.1) with VS 2012 Ultimate and VS 2013 Professional, run debug tests back and forth, stripping certain parts of the program, searched MDSN, Google and StackExchange - to no avail. This freeze also happens when I handle `WM_COMMAND` of a child window. There was also no such issue when I tried implementing GDI+, but it proved to be highly ineffective, hence the switch to DirectX. Aside from that, the program runs flawlessly. I hope I've provided enough information.

Comment: Instead of triggering the rendering in your main loop using `InvalidateRect`, why not just call your `OnRender` function directly?

Comment: @JonathanPotter That's what I'm doing as of now actually. The point is, this method works perfectly once I move the mouse or hit a key. I wish to know why that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You have not been clear about what you are doing to run "various background processes."  That is probably where the "stuck" issue comes from. A suggestion is to move that out of the message loop. Instead, call SetTimer during window initialization and then do a bit of your background process work each time the WM_TIMER message comes in.

And, when you want a WM_PAINT to come in call InvalidateRect().

Comment: By "various background processes" I, of course, meant that they are irrelevant to this issue. And as I've stated, the entire `FOR` loop is functional, so the `InvalidateRect` still gets called 30 times a second without `WM_PAINT` being executed. Step-by-step debug method as well as direct observation reveals just that. The rest of the app acts as if nothing was wrong, and yet refuses to draw.

Comment: WM_PAINT is a low priority message. It is held until the message queue is empty. If you are continuously processing a stream of other messages WM_PAINT will not come in.